# C++ exec executed bash scripts stops randomly

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, execvp

I'm executing a bash script via execvp but the script stops execution half-way.

Have a look at my code:

```
int main()
{
    char* params[2];
    //First Parameter has to be the executable path
    params[0] = (char*) ::malloc(sizeof(char) * 40);
    ::strcpy(params[0], "/home/test.sh");
    //execv needs an null pointer as last argument
    params[1] = NULL;

    //Execute target executable
    ::execvp(params[0], params);

    //Only if ::exec() returns: output error
    std::cout << "Exec Failed!";

    exit(1);
}
```

I used the following bash script for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
echo "1" >> /home/out.txt
echo "2" >> /home/out.txt
echo "3" >> /home/out.txt
echo "4" >> /home/out.txt
echo "5" >> /home/out.txt

exit 0
```

Most times the script doesn't even execute, means no file is being created or nothing is being written into an existing file. Somtimes, however the script executes partially or even complete meaning the textfile contains

```
1
```

up to

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But no matter what happens inside the bash script the application always exits with error code 0.

Why is this happening?

If i execute the bash script manually everything works fine reaching the end of my script every time. Therefore, i assume it has to do something with my execvp call instead of the bash script.

I'm running, therefore tested the program on an beaglebone black system (am335x) with debian 8.6.

Comment: Did you check errno for more details?

Comment: execvp does not return

Comment: It still might set errno

Comment: How do i access errno after my exec call?

Comment: Ok if execvp does not return, how does your program end? does it crash? do you have to kill it? what is its exit code if it does not crash?

Comment: Exit code is 0, and execvp never returns if the passed application can be executed. The context gets replaced entirely. That is exactly what makes debugging this so hard.

Comment: I am not confined that the platform justifies tagging this [embedded], it may be embedded, but the question is not specific to embedded systems.  You might get a wider audience by being less specific.

Comment: If your code is C++, why have you tagged C?

Comment: Does the file `test.sh` have execute permission? `chmod +x test.sh`

Comment: It has. If using `system()` everything works fine but since it's insecure i would like to use `fork()`+`exec()`

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did to make this program work:

Note: I re-wrote it in C

The proposed C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit()
#include <string.h>  // strcpy()
#include <unistd.h>  // execvp()


int main( void )
{
    char* params[2];
    //First Parameter has to be the executable path
    params[0] = "/home/rkwill/rtest.sh";
    //execv needs an null pointer as last argument
    params[1] = NULL;

    //Execute target executable
    execvp(params[0], params);
    perror( "execvp failed" );
    exit(1);
}
```

then, in my user directory: /home/rkwill/

```
touch rtest.sh
```

then edited 'rtest.sh' to contain:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

# generate file if not already in existence
touch /home/rkwill/out.txt

echo "1" >> /home/rkwill/out.txt
echo "2" >> /home/rkwill/out.txt
echo "3" >> /home/rkwill/out.txt
echo "4" >> /home/rkwill/out.txt
echo "5" >> /home/rkwill/out.txt

exit 0
```

Then made the bash script executable via

```
chmod 777 rtest.sh
```

Note: I used the directory /home/rkwill because I do not have permission to write in the /home directory.

the first time I ran the program the resulting 'out.txt file contained

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

each successive run appended a repeat of the above output to 'out.txt'